# foreach between Ienumerable

Tags: c#

i have a simple question about entity .
i have a simple method it makes simple inner join between two table in db ,
now returned type is anonymous i think ,
if i use  IEnumerable  like below it works fine and when i fill datagridview it works good but how can i move between IEnumerable and retrieve my object because their are anonymous types and we can not use this:

```
foreach(var o in result)
 o.Id //did not have a type and is not accessible

????? Testmethod()
{
  IEnumerable<object> result;

   using (var context = new TestDBEntities())
    {


         result = (from a in context.Table1
              join b in context.Table2
                  on a.ID equals b.Id
              select new { b.Id ,b.name });
           }

 return ???
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot pass anonymous types between methods (well you can, but not strongly typed and it would be a bad workaround at best). Best approach is to define a simple class for this that you can use in your projection:

```
public class Foo
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Now you can use `Foo` in your query and return an `IEnumerable<Foo>` as result:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> Testmethod()
{
    using(var context = new TestDBEntities())
    {
         var result = (from a in context.Table1
                       join b in context.Table2
                       on a.ID equals b.Id
                       select new Foo() { Id = b.Id , Name = b.name });
         return result.ToList();//force materializing results
    }
 }
```